# Remove spacing around italics in ggplot axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making the plot copied below. However, when I italicize the `n` in the label, it adds spacing after it. How can the spacing around italics be controlled? Here is a minimal version of the code:

```
ggplot(data.frame()) + 
    labs(labs(x=expression("Proportion of "~italic(n)-"gram Model (1-"*gamma*")")))
```

This is the actual plot:

[image]

Full code (data is too large to post):

```
ggplot(all_pplx, aes(x=(1-Weight), y=perplexity_val)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=`n-gram`)) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  # scale_x_reverse() +
  labs(title="",
       x=expression("Proportion of "~italic("n")-"gram Model ("*gamma*")"),
       y="Perplexity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 1, size=12),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=12,face="bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=12),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=12),
        legend.position = c(0.15, 0.7), 
        legend.background = element_rect(color = "black", 
                                         fill = "grey90", 
                                         size = .2, 
                                         linetype = "solid")) +
  ggsave('emnlp_new-exp1.pdf', device='pdf')
```

Comment: Make your example [minimal and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't have your data. In this case, the graph itself is irrelevant, so you can make a much simpler example, e.g. `ggplot(data.frame()) + labs(labs(x=expression(italic(n)-"gram (1-"*gamma*")")))`

Comment: Thanks! I never realized I could use `data.frame()`

Comment: You can use `paste()` with `plotmath` expressions to build this: `expression(paste("Proportion of ", italic("n"), "-gram Model ", (1-gamma)))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the `-` to get interpreted as a hyphen, not a minus sign, so include it in the string part. Then connect the string to italics with `*`, which places symbols next to each other, instead of `~`, which leaves space.

On the other hand, the (1-γ) *should* be formatted as math.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame()) + 
    labs(x = expression("Proportion of"~italic(n)*"-gram Model"~(1-gamma)))
```

[image]

Docs at `?plotmath`.